# Extract MAC and IP from file, place in hash, and print hash in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I am writing a perl program for a project that will read a file that contains an IP Address and a MAC Address like so:

```
#host itvm28-5.it.cs.umb.edu {
#    hardware ethernet 00:0c:29:fe:bf:b5;
#    fixed-address 10.0.0.167;
#}
```

There are many line like this with different IP and MAC address combos.  What I would like to do is extract the IP and MAC with reg expressions and then pair them together next to each other.  I've got something that I believe kind of works but it is printing duplicates.  I believe in some cases it does not match up either.

Below is the code that I currently have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open( DHCP, '<', 'dhcpd.conf' ) or die $!;
while ( my $addr = <DHCP> ) {
    if ( $addr =~ /(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/ ) {
        @ip = ($1);
    }
    if ( $addr =~ /(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[-:]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\.){2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})/ ) {
        @mac = ($1);
    }

    my %ipmac;
    @ipmac{@ip} = @mac;
    print %ipmac, "\n";
}
close DHCP;
```

Below is the output that I am currently getting with this program:

```
10.0.0.16300:0c:29:a1:2f:69
10.0.0.16300:0c:29:a1:2f:69
10.0.0.16300:0c:29:a1:2f:69
10.0.0.16300:0c:29:c6:40:2a
10.0.0.16400:0c:29:c6:40:2a
10.0.0.16400:0c:29:c6:40:2a
10.0.0.16400:0c:29:c6:40:2a
10.0.0.16400:0c:29:c6:40:2a
10.0.0.16400:0c:29:b9:24:c5
10.0.0.16500:0c:29:b9:24:c5
10.0.0.16500:0c:29:b9:24:c5
10.0.0.16500:0c:29:b9:24:c5
10.0.0.16500:0c:29:b9:24:c5
10.0.0.16500:0c:29:94:c0:85
10.0.0.16600:0c:29:94:c0:85
10.0.0.16600:0c:29:94:c0:85
10.0.0.16600:0c:29:94:c0:85
10.0.0.16600:0c:29:94:c0:85
10.0.0.16600:0c:29:fe:bf:b5
10.0.0.16700:0c:29:fe:bf:b5
10.0.0.16700:0c:29:fe:bf:b5
10.0.0.16700:0c:29:fe:bf:b5
```

As you can see, some of the IP Addresses will contain more than one MAC Address.  Even worse than that, we can see that it's duplicated the key,value pair.  Can anyone see within my code why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Thanks a ton,
Ryan

Comment: Are the # from inputs there for real ?

Comment: @sputnick In the file that I am grabbing the input from, they are there.  The file is intended only to test with.

Comment: What does your real data look like. How do you associate an ip address with a mac address? Do you want to associate multiple mac's to a single ip, or both in multiples? You can have a hash of both separately, each value containing an array reference. Then its possible to cross reference?

Comment: @sln My file looks like a bunch of lines similar to the first block of code that I had put at the top.  I want only to associate the IP Address with the Mac Address within the block only.  There are no duplicates in the file so there must be something wrong with my code as it is causing duplicates - I do not want this.  Currently, I am associating the ip and mac by grabbing both by reg expressions and then putting them into a hash which you see in my programs code but again, is not working.

Comment: How should output look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is executing once for every line in your input file, and you're printing in every loop (so you're printing one output line for every input line you have).

You didn't declare `@ip` or `@mac` explicitly, which means they have file scope, ie. they maintain the values they had from the previous iteration of the loop. This is why you're getting repeated printouts.

The best way to work with the data set you have is to change your `$/` (input record separator) to `"\n}\n"` so that you get an entire record in each `<DHCP>` read, and then you'll be doing one loop per actual input record, not per line.